# Delay between opacity: 0 and starting animation to opacity: 1 in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael JS library and here is my code:

```
 var rectangle = paper.rect(0, 0, 5, 5);                        
    rectangle.attr({opacity: 0});
    // I need here a 5 seconds delay, before starting an animation
    rectangle.animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
```

I have tried  `rectangle.attr({opacity: 0}).delay(5000);` and also this: `rectangle.attr({opacity: 0}, 5000);` , but none of these seems to work at all.

What is the simplest way to wait some time before excuting other code. I would not like to use nested functions or for loops at all, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Raphael.animation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.animation) and [Animation.delay](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Animation.delay).

```
var anim = Raphael.animation({opacity: 0, opacity: 1}, 1000);
rectangle.animate(anim.delay(5000 /* the delay (ms) */));
```