# Raphael delay animation

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

```
function object() {
    circle.animate({cx: 100, cy: -200, r: 100}, 100, 'ease-out');
}

object();
```

I am starting with Raphael and trying to create an animation. However I don't understand how the Animation delay object works.

I need to be able to delay the object to let the other objects finish their animation. Also how would you change the color of this object at the end of its animation?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626589/delay-between-opacity-0-and-starting-animation-to-opacity-1-in-raphael-js

Comment: Thanks for the reply after fiddling with it for quite some time i was able to solve it :D.